# Why 'covariant' is used when the method is not overridden?

Tags: dart

From [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/791edc230db53c55401a8340b18ffc46d21299df/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart#L1262):

```
bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<T> oldClipper);
```

AFAIK, the keyword `covariant` is used when you override a method explicitly telling the analyzer that you're going to provide it a valid type. But in `CustomClipper` class, there's no such override, so why `covariant` is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mark a parameter as `covariant` in the superclass, then subclasses automatically get their parameters marked `covariant` too.

If the class is intended to be extended, this can be a service (and documentation) for the subclass authors so they know that the parameter is supposed to be used covariantly.

If you look at [this subclass](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3fd3447f9676b71d91ee81e32f335c702cef8e7c/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart#L473), you can see that they declare:

```dart
@override
bool shouldReclip(_DecorationClipper oldClipper) {...}
```

which is covariantly overriding the parameter type `CustomClipper<Path>` with `_DeclarationClipper` (which implements `CustomClipper<Path>`), and they don't have to write `covariant` here because the superclass declared it for them.

Comment: Thank you Lrn, so basically it is like by using `covariant` in superclass, we let the subclass to omit the need of `covariant`.